# Why the navigation bar tint color is faded?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm currently working on an iOS application in swift. Here I have `UIView` on the top of the screen and have `UINavigationController`. And I need the topView and navigationBar color to be same. And I gave the topBar background color and `navigationBar` tint color as same. But when the screen loads, the `navigationController` is showing a faded color. Why?
I tried through programmatically,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Also, I tried through storyboard, like giving the navigationBar's tintColor as red. But in both ways, it's not working.
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` to have a solid color navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

By default the property translucent is set to yes which desaturates any color applied to the navigation bar.

To disable this behaviour just select the navigation bar in your storyboard and disable the checkbox labeled "translucent" in the attribute inspector.